# Connection Failure to remote server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-datapower

I have a sample app and when I deploy it on the Localhost MobileFirst Server, it successfully connects to the wlapp. When I try to connect the wlapp on my remote server, it fails. After checking the logs, I found out that the URL "https://MyServerIp:Port/MyContextRoot/**authorization/vl/clients/instance**" is incorrect according to the URL I usually hit. I have been trying to search that where this URL generates so that I could modify it according to my need. I have highlighted the part of the URL which is incorrect.

Comment: Provide the full error and not just a part of it.

Comment: The part that I have highlighted is the issue.

Comment: I am sorry for that but, I'm not allowed to provide full logs due to some restrictions. My questions was simple that where this URL gets generated when we try to hit the data power.

Comment: Did you open a PMR? Can you remove this question?

Comment: Yaa I'll raise a PMR today and then I'll remove this question.

Comment: I have finally found the solution to the problem. We can change the URL used to connect the datapower by modifying the code in worklight.js.

Comment: Modifying worklight.js is highly not advised. This file will get regenerated on each build.

Comment: Thats why I have maintained a backup copy of it. And in my case, I don't need the Datapower URL which is generated by default.

Comment: Can you please either write an answer, or remove the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `https://MyServerIp:Port/MyContextRoot/authorization/vl/clients/instance`, the "authorization/vl/clients/instance" part is a constant and you need not change it. However the first part of the "myServerIp" and "Port" is something you need to once moving to a remote server.

To change it, you need to build the application with the correct values. See the instructions in the following user documentation topic on Build Settings and Deploy Target: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html?lang=en

Comment: OK. Thanks Idan. We have got some inputs from IBM too. We are working on it.